# how can I customise style of permission alert message for web push notifications in browser using css, if it is possible?

Tags: css, web, push-notification, push, alert

[image: push notification customise]
Apart from this, I also want to know how to build my own service-worker web push notification system(even when web-app is not open in any tab). Currently, I am using pushpad as an alternative to this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize the styles of this permission popups.